# custom taxonomy and custom post type url conflict

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, urls

i am having one serious url issue.

there is **news** custom post type. it's slug is **news**.

News taxonomy slug: **news_category**

News taxonomy url is:  http://domain.com/news_category/press-release

i want to change the url of the **news_category** to news **news** .

so url of news taxonomy would be:

```
             http://domain.com/news/press-release
```

i tried to rewrite the slug **news_category** to **news** but that's creating conflict issue. news shows news url  but all the posts of news post type are returning **404 not found**

News post's url:

```
     http://domain.com/news/POST_TITLE
```

as posts url also contain the news slug both conflicts. getting 404 error.

is it possible to fix it?  how can i fix it?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course it will not work because WordPress will always look for item "POST_TITLE" from custom post type `news` when it sees `news` in URL. And since WordPress will not find anything, WordPress will return 404 error.

Comment: can you please help me to get solution?  how to fix it?

Comment: There is nothing to do. Both cannot work simultaneously. Either you can have category slug `news` or post type `news`. You should change slug for one.

Comment: is it possible to set taxonomy term before the custom post type's url.  for expample:   http://domain.com/news/press-release/post_title     is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It may help you.

```
 class Tax_Seo_Perma {

  public function __construct() {
    // Hooks
    add_filter('rewrite_rules_array',array($this, 'create_rewrite_rules'));
    add_filter('wp_loaded', array($this, 'flush_rules'));
    add_filter('post_link', array($this, 'modify_link_addresses'), 10, 3);
    //add_filter('post_type_link', 'tsp_write_link_addresses', 10, 3);
}

public function flush_rules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); 
}

public function create_rewrite_rules($rewrite) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // loop through custom taxonomies
    $args = array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false 
    );
    $output             = 'names'; // or objects
    $operator           = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
    $custom_taxonomies  = get_taxonomies($args, $output, $operator); 
    if ($custom_taxonomies) {
        foreach ($custom_taxonomies as $tax_name ) {
            $tax_token = '%'.$tax_name.'%';
            $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag($tax_token, '(.+)', $tax_name.'=');
        }
    }

    // read current permalink structure and set the same structre
    $keywords_rewrite = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite->root.$wp_rewrite->permalink_structure);
    return ( $rewrite + $keywords_rewrite );
}

public function modify_link_addresses($permalink, $post_id, $leavename)
{
    global $blog_id;
    global $wp_rewrite;
    // this is user's permalink structure set in options
    $permastruct = $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure;

    $args = array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false 
    );
    $output             = 'names'; // or objects
    $operator           = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
    $custom_taxonomies  = get_taxonomies($args, $output, $operator);

    if ($custom_taxonomies) {
        foreach ($custom_taxonomies as $tax_name ) {
            $tax_token = '%'.$tax_name.'%';

            $tax_terms = get_the_terms( $post->id, $tax_name );
            //var_dump($tax_terms);
            if ( !empty($tax_terms) )
            {
                foreach($tax_terms as $a_term)
                {
                    $long_slug = $a_term->slug;
                    if( false != (int)$a_term->parent ) { // a's parent p exists
                        $p_term = get_term( (int)$a_term->parent, $tax_name );//var_dump($p_term->slug);
                        $long_slug = ($p_term->slug) ? $p_term->slug .'+'. $long_slug : $long_slug;
                    } 
                    if( false != (int)$a_term->parent AND false != (int)$p_term->parent ) { // p's parent g exists
                        $g_term = get_term( (int)$p_term->parent, $tax_name );
                        $long_slug = ($g_term->slug) ? $g_term->slug .'+'. $long_slug : $long_slug;
                    }

                    $permalink = str_replace($tax_token, $long_slug, $permalink);
                    break;
                }
            } else {$permalink = str_replace($tax_token, 'no-'.$tax_name, $permalink); }
        }
    }

    return $permalink;
 }
 }
```

Comment: i will try this code and let you know it works or not ASAP. Thanks